# Workaround for Perl threading on a cPanel server

Tags: multithreading, perl, cpanel

I am developing a perl script to generate DNSSEC keys for several thousand domains. Since key generation is a bit slow, it is taking so much time when the number of keys to generate are on 10000s. As a workaround, I was trying to use Perl threads to spawn new threads and distribute the work. ( the script needs to be run on a cPanel server ) As it turns out cPanel perl does not have support for threads. I cannot recompile the perl in the server as it is a production server and many things would break.

What are my options? Basically, I want to distribute the load to multiple cores and decrease the total time required for the script. Is forking an option?, if so, how I would go about using it?

Comment: Forking is okay if you are fine with generating files for each key - I have no idea if you need everything in one central place or not.

Comment: This is the case : I have 10000 domains in the server. I need to generate DNSSEC keys (ZSK and KSK) for each of them, and sign each domain with the appropriate key. The current setup I have is a single threaded script, which will do it one by one. I need a way to speed it up. :)

Comment: Parallel::ForkManager. It can even return values back to the parent.

Answer (score 0):

Check this [tutorial](http://perlmaven.com/fork) as a good example for forking.
You may need to estimate a bit the time needed per domain to spawn the right amount of child processes without overloading your machine.